# Api which checks domain validity

Tags: php, json, api

Can anyone refer me to a json api I can use to confirm the validity of a domain name in a PHP script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not need an api,
you can check with a DNS query if the domain name really exists or not.

PHP `checkdnsrr` — Check DNS records corresponding to a given Internet host name or IP address

example of domain check:

```
<?php
function validate_domain($domain){

      //Check the DNS if the domain has an MX record
      if(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX")){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
}
?>
```

example of email validation with reg exp + dns check

```
<?php
function validate_email($email){

   $exp = "^[a-z\'0-9]+([._-][a-z\'0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([._-][a-z0-9]+))+$";

   if(eregi($exp,$email)){

      if(checkdnsrr(array_pop(explode("@",$email)),"MX")){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }

   }else{

      return false;
   }    
}
?>
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php

Comment: So how would I implement this?

Comment: call validate_domain("doaminname.com") and you have true if the domain really exists

Comment: Don't worry, I took it out of the function and used the if(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX")) which works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two function for checking the website valid or not

```
 function is_website_valid() {
    if ( $headers && ( @$headers[0]=='HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found' || @$headers[1]=='HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found' ) ) {
        return 'invalid';
    }
    elseif ( !is_array( $headers ) ) {
        return 'invalid';
    }
    else {
        return 'valid';
    }
}
 function get_website_headers($website) {
    ini_set( "user_agent", "Mozilla custom agent" );
    $headers = get_headers( $website, 1 );
    return $headers;
}
$status = array('website'=>$website,'status'=>is_website_valid());
echo json_encode($status);
```

Comment: And how would I implement them?

Comment: can you put what you implemented for same , so i can  help you for the same